# Simple Lambda map function stopped working, get error "list not callable"

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

This very simple lambda map function used to work on Google Colaboratory but does not anymore.  Gives me error " 'list' object is not callable".  Anyone know why?

Result should be [2, 4, 6]

```
a=[1,2,3]
print(list(map(lambda x:x*2,a)))
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a variable named `list`?

Comment: This is how pretty much all simple examples on web are setup, and used to work so stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have a variable named `list`, you are overriding the original `list` instance.

Here is an example:

```
>>> type(list)
<class 'type'>
>>> list = 'foo'
>>> type(list)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

As you can see it becomes a string.

Comment: I have to say, I love my strongly typed languages... (sorry, that was probably uncalled for)

Comment: @Randall Show me your whole code, or use a list comprehension instead of `map`, like this `[x * 2 for x in a]`

Comment: And did you run it in a fresh environment?

Comment: @Matthias yes! that was it!!! Went to Runtime menu and Restarted Runtime.  This solved it! Now it works.  But why does this happen? Thanks!

Comment: @Randall In your previous codes you probably assigned `list` as a variable name, and it still kept in the session. Remember to accept and upvote as well :)

Comment: @U11-Forward solved with Matthias help above.  But thanks for the for statement option.

Comment: That was what everyone tried to explain. In the running session you did something like `list = [1, 2, 3]` and you overwrote the built-in `list`.

Comment: Got it.  NEVER name anything a list. ;)

Answer (score 1):

list() is a built-in function.

If you code:

```
list = [1,2,3]
```

...you've now overridden the function with an actual list which is not callable